# How to get status of "opatch prereq CheckApplicable" via script

Tags: oracle, scripting

I want to check if a patch is Applicable via

```
opatch prereq CheckApplicable -oh <oracle home> -ph <patch home>
```

but the returncode is always 0! It doesn't matter if the text output says

```
"... Prereq "checkApplicable" for patch 19121548 failed ..."
```

or if it succeeded.

I would prefer not to parse the output of opatch prereq. Only if I have no other chance.

Comment: How do you access the return code? I have just tried it with `echo $?`, return code is same as opatch error code, works as intended.

Comment: opatch prereq CheckApplicable -oh <oracle home> -ph <patch home> always returns RC=0 if the command can be executed. If it can't be executed because, let's say the -oh <oracle home> is invalid, it will return something <> RC=0. But always when the command will is able to complete, disregarding the text output, it returns rc=0

Comment: Can you post a sample output and the platform? As I said, it works like this: http://pastebin.com/L2J46Kvm

Comment: Yes, see http://pastebin.com/q6vVdxiG please. The home is 11.2.0.4 enterprise edition and the patch is PSU 11.2.0.3.14 and I would expect that this patch should faild because you can't apply 11.2.0.3.14 to 11.2.0.4 rdbms home. See the last line with the $? of opatch

Comment: Sorry, missed the release: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3  (x86_64)

Comment: Interesting. Tried the same versions, got the correct output: http://pastebin.com/Q3sYreY8
In your run, last line says `OPatch succeeded.`, even though all checks failed. In my output, last line says `OPatch failed with error code 1`, and I got that value as return code. The only difference I see is that you use an older version of OPatch. Can you try the same with the newest version of OPatch? I had problems with installing the previous 11.2.0.3 PSU, because the README incorrectly stated the required OPatch version was 11.2.0.3.0 or higher, but it actually needed 11.2.0.3.6 or higher.

Comment: Finally it's working! http://pastebin.com/ZxYdbNBF Thanks @BalazsPapp I guess I have to do more checks for OPatch Version. But it seems a little strange that my first opatch "test output" indicated that the patch can't be applyed but but rc was 0 :-)